# Analysis on why NULL values in a column

Tags: null

Please help me understand how to do analysis on why I am getting NULL Values in a column when I am usually getting valid data in that specific column? I appreciate all the help.

Comment: A minimum reproducible example would help everyone interested to help.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.